# send parameter to 2 webparts on the page, preferably with Ajax?

Tags: search, data-view-web-part, ajax

In SharePoint Server 2010, We have a List with items and their details.  User profiles have an  indexed field that contains items matching the list titles. 
I want to display a dataview with just the item titles- When the user clicks the title I want to send the selected row to a connected webpart that will display all the details for the selected item AND ALSO to send the title of the selected row to a PeopleSearch Results webpart on the page and perform the search.  Preferably all this would be done with AJAX/without a postback.

I can connect the titles to the details, but I don't know how to ALSO update the search results.
I want to do this w/o any custom webparts.  I'm OK with using javascript/jquery.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely go with jQuery if you don't want a postback. You won't be able to do anything with Web Part Connections without that postback, but you can call the Lists and Query Web Services and probably accomplish what you describe. Take a look at SPServices for this: http://spservices.codeplex.com

Comment: if I use jQuery, would the recommendation be to put a search webpart on a separate page then use jquery to do a call to that page, passing the query parameters I want - then basically screenscrape the results area and put them on the main page?  I was hoping there might be some built-in SharePoint 2010 methods to do this kind of thing...

Comment: Search is available in the SharePoint Web Services. It is also available in Marc's library: http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Search&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices